# Why do we only consider two points in Young’s double slit experiment?

Tags: waves, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, experimental-technique, huygens-principle

Say we have two slits in the xy-plane. The x distance between them is d. Why do we, when calculating the resulting amplitude of the wave, consider only the phase difference of two secondary radial wave sources of equal y coordinate? Why do then we need two slits, but not just two tiny holes?

Comment: It goes by the name (title)

Comment: Two holes work as well. The pattern will be different on the wall, but the pattern perpendicular to the two holes it works out the same. Much easier to make thin slits than a really tiny hole, particularly 100+ years ago.

Answer (score 0):

First, the space of double split experiment was actually approximated in 2d rather than 3d. The double split experiment that's extending in one direction in the form of split might be to reduce the effect of a third spacial dimension. It's hard to make a small perfect round hole rather than cut a rectangle slit because of the relative uncertainty and error in the geometry. The double split also allow larger intensity of the interference pattern to be observed given the equipment limit. The modern experiments suggested that it's not necessarily to be done with split at all (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment).

Second, double split is much easier to calculate and to teach in class. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment)

The triple split experiment also existed (https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1007/1007.4193.pdf) and the interference pattern was shown(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcE4YeUNphk).